# Docker permission denied on login and everything i try

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I am new to docker and I get permission denied on everything i try or not found. I cannot install anything to any docker container and nothing seems to work. I have had others look and no one seems to know why every docker container fails to work for me. Here is an example:

```
sudo docker run -it ubuntu
[sudo] password for user: 
bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
root@ac9449598270:/# vi test.txt
bash: vi: command not found
root@ac9449598270:/# apt-get install vim
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01-vendor-ubuntu - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-autoremove-suggests - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-gzip-indexes - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-no-languages - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Error reading the CPU table
```

Edit:

running docker with sudo produces the following error:

```
docker run -it ubuntu
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Edit 2:
I am on PopOS. Its on a system 76 machine. I have tried running as root and that doesnt help.

Edit 3:
typing groups shows

```
groups
user adm sudo
```

So as per @alex067 suggestion I added the docker group with the following commands

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -a -G docker user
```

After running the commands I now have a docker group and I have been added to the group. The error is the following

```
sudo docker run -it ubuntu
bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
root@a7a80c8426db:/# apt update
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01-vendor-ubuntu - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-autoremove-suggests - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-gzip-indexes - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-no-languages - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Error reading the CPU table
root@a7a80c8426db:/#
```

I also tried to restart docker and receive the following error

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
Failed to restart docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.
```

Comment: Why do you run `docker` with `sudo`?

Comment: @tripleee because hasn't read the post-install steps in the documentation?

Comment: Also depends on the host OS. Red Hat requires you to be `root` but then there will be other circumstances around that. If the OP is on a Debian-based platform your comment makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like your user on your host machine doesn't have permission to use the docker engine (or socket? not sure the difference).

You can verify this using `group` to view which groups your user is a part of. You should see "docker" as one of the groups.

If not, that is your problem.

You can add your user to the docker group (which provides permissions to use the docker engine), by doing

```
usermod -a -G docker my_user
```

This will add the docker group as secondary group to your user.

After that, it may be a good idea to restart the docker engine, with:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: I was getting the "bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied" after upgrading from Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 20. Previously, I had always run docker as root. Perhaps they added some security measure to prevent running Docker as root, I don't know. Anyway, I added my user to the docker group and running it as that, but still got the same error message. The key to making it work as restarting Docker. Now I can login to Docker without getting the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

So after asking on the popOS chat I found out that I needed to update to at least popOS 19.10 and that I needed to install docker using the following command

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

I was also told to install the nvidia container for being able to use the gpu with the following command

```
sudo apt install nvidia-container-runtime
```

After that docker works for me.

(Special thanks to @mmstick from the popOS chat for the tips)

Answer (score 3):

I got this same issue when installing docker via Snap on Manjaro. Root user inside containers didn't seem to have permissions to access any files.

After googling for hours I resolved by installing docker using the package manager instead of Snap.

Comment: mmmm why do you think it was snap??

Comment: this helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Was getting the same permission error after creating a container and logging onto it via the console. Running Xubuntu:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Had initially installed Docker using a program called "Software" (supplied with the OS) for installing via the GUI.

Googling suggested adding my user to the docker group to no avail, so uninstalled Docker using "Software" then re-installed Docker using a package manager instead, as outlined here:

[How To Install and Use Docker on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04)

After installing using this method I no longer received the permission error.